# Redirecting Sub-directories with Backbone.js and/or htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, backbone.js, path, url-rewriting, router

After many hours of research and tinkering, I've finally managed to get backbone.js routes working, with one exception: 
If I enter "/workingdir/routepath" - everything is great and it uses the 'routpath' route, however if I enter "/workingdir/routepath/" or "/workingdir/routepath/asdf" or anything similar, my website breaks and I get errors that look somewhat like this:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:  "http://example.com/staging/personal/css/style.css". fj:5
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/staging/personal/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js". fj:6
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/staging/personal/scripts/nav.js". fj:6
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/staging/personal/scripts/underscore-min.js". fj:6
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < underscore-min.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/staging/personal/scripts/backbone-min.js". fj:6
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < backbone-min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

And the page has no styling whatsoever. I think the issue is coming from the slash in the URL, making the paths for css and js files point to the wrong location (they should be in "staging/css/" and "staging/scripts/", but as the log indicates, it's looking for "staging/personal/xxx").

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you please make all of your example paths consistent if they're not already?  E.g. does `workindir` correspond to `staging` or anything else?  Also, `example.com` (or one of it's relatives) is generally your best bet for a domain name placeholder in examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative path references will be resolved differently depending on whether the request URI has a trailing slash or not.  I imagine that's what's causing your problem.  Consider these links:

```
<!-- Relative path references -->

<link href="staging/css/style1.css">

<link href="./staging/css/style2.css">


<!-- Absolute path reference -->

<link href="/workingdir/staging/css/style3.css">
```

This is how those paths will be resolved depending on the request URI:

```
REQUEST_URI = /workingdir/routepath

/workingdir/staging/css/style1.css

/workingdir/staging/css/style2.css

/workingdir/staging/css/style3.css


REQUEST_URI = /workingdir/routepath/

/workingdir/routepath/staging/css/style1.css

/workingdir/routepath/staging/css/style2.css

/workingdir/staging/css/style3.css
```

So if you want the ability to make the request with a trailing slash or additional segments, you'll want to use an absolute path reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share with others having this issue. I had the same problem, but now with a different solution. These additions to .htaccess didn't work out initially:

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType text/css .css 
AddType text/javascript .js
AddType text/css .css
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/woff .woff
AddType font/woff .woff
AddType font/opentype .woff
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes
```

Finally, I realized that while my path below worked on localhost, the CASE-sensitive server did not accept the path

```
\js\prettyPhoto\js\jquery.prettyPhoto.js
```

instead of

```
\js\prettyphoto\js\jquery.prettyPhoto.js
```

The CAPITAL p was making all those errors! It might be too, for your case, since you have "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " and "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:"

Let me know if it help : )